# Find the leading singular behavior of a parameter-dependent double integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, asymptotics

The integral
$$S(\eta)=\int^1_{-1}\int^1_{-1} \sqrt{x^2+\eta y^2 +\eta^2 +y^4}dx dy$$
is not real-analytic at $\eta\to 0^+$. The question is to **find out its leading singular behavior at $\eta\to 0^+$**. Numerical results seem to suggest the behavior $S(\eta) \propto \eta^{5/2}$, i.e. $S'''(\eta)$ diverges as $1/\sqrt{\eta}$ when $\eta\to 0^+$.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks. But could you explain why the $y^4$ term can be neglected while the $\eta y^2$ term mus be kept?

Comment: Constructing an ODE for $S$ and applying the Frobenius method gives $c_{5/2} \eta^{5/2}$ plus a power series (so $S(\eta) - c_{5/2} \eta^{5/2}$ is analytic). If $f(\eta, y)$ is the result of integrating out $x$, then we can take $y = u \sqrt \eta$ and interchange the integral wrt $u$ and the limit to obtain
$$c_{5/2} = \lim_{\eta \to 0^+} \eta^{-5/2} \int_{-1}^1
 (f(\eta, y) - f(0, y) - f_\eta(0, y) \eta - f_{\eta \eta}(0, y) \eta^2/2) dy =
-4 \pi \sqrt 3/5.$$

Comment: @MarkViola Replacing the integrand with $g(\eta, x, y) = \sqrt {x^2 + \eta y^2 + \eta^2}$ won't work though, because $y^4$ is not $o(\eta y^2 + \eta^2)$ when $(\eta, y) \to (0+, 0)$. Also, it's not quite clear what you're estimating (we can't estimate $S(0)$ with the integral of $g(0, x, y)$).

Comment: @maxim Yes, upon my writing the now-deleted comment, I had thought (incorrectly) that we could approximate the integral of interest by adding and subtracting an integral with integrand $\sqrt{x^2+\eta y^2+\eta^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem for the inner integral
$$\int^1_{-1} \sqrt{x^2+\eta y^2 +\eta^2 +y^4}\,dx =$$
$$\sqrt{\eta ^2+y^4+\eta  y^2+1}+\frac 12 (\eta ^2+y^4+\eta  y^2)\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\eta ^2+y^4+\eta  y^2+1}+1}{\sqrt{\eta ^2+y^4+\eta 
   y^2+1}-1}\right)$$ For the outer antiderivative no problem except a bunch of elliptic integrals of all kinds. The resulting integral is just a monster.

The only thing which is simple is to evaluate the value of the definite integral for $\eta=0$; it is
$$k=\frac{2}{15} \left(-8 \,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{4};-1\right)+15 \sqrt{2}+3 \sinh
   ^{-1}(1)+\frac{6 \sqrt{2 \pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}\right)\sim 2.66132$$ But is seems to me that, from numerical calculations, using
$$S(\eta)=k +a\, \eta^b$$  it *seems* to me that $b\sim  \frac 54$

To allow a double check, I give below a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\eta & S(\eta)- k \\
 0.0 & 0.00000 \\
 0.1 & 0.13385 \\
 0.2 & 0.32357 \\
 0.3 & 0.55336 \\
 0.4 & 0.81345 \\
 0.5 & 1.09701 \\
 0.6 & 1.39905 \\
 0.7 & 1.71580 \\
 0.8 & 2.04440 \\
 0.9 & 2.38266 \\
 1.0 & 2.72884
\end{array}
\right)$$

I have been unable to expand $S(\eta)$ as a series around $\eta=0$.

Comment: In fact, $S(\eta) = k + c_1 \eta + c_2 \eta^2 + c_{5/2} \eta^{5/2} + \sum_{n \geq 3} c_n \eta^n$, where
$$c_1 = 2 (2 \, {_2 F_1}(1/2, 3/4; 7/4; -1) + 3 \ln(\sqrt 2 + 1))/9, \\
c_2 = 7 \Gamma^2(5/4)/\sqrt \pi + 2 \ln(\sqrt 2 + 1)$$
and $c_n$ is a function of $k, c_1, c_2$.

Comment: @Maxim. Impressive ! How did you make it ? If you use Mathematica, could you send me the syntax on a PDF file. I am curious. My e-mail address is in my profile. Thanks and cheers. :-)

Comment: $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be computed in the same way as $c_{5/2}$ in the comment below the question: $c_1 = \int_{-1}^1 f_\eta(0, y) dy$, $c_2 = \int_{-1}^1 f_{\eta \eta}(0, y) dy/2$.